# how to pass object back to calling code from within a delegate in javascript

Tags: javascript, delegates, jscript

```
function test(parm) {
    var clientContext = new ClientContext(parm);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    ); 
}
function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    var listItemInfo = '';
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    var dict = {};

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        dict['key'] = oListItem.get_id();
        dict['value'] = oListItem.get_item('Title');
    }
}
```

what I want to do is to pass the dictionary object (dict) which I created in the onQuerySuceeded back to the calling function test. Is there an easy way to do that?